# Hide or remove next button after 3 clicks and show again if click on previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have done some basic jquery code when clicking 3 time on next button it hides and when you click on previous button it shows but than it doesn't run the 3 click loop. I need to make after clicking 3 time on next button when you click on previous button it should run the first loop which is 3 click.

```
var $i = 1; 
        $('body').on('click','#next',function(){ 
                if ($i < 3) { /*functions to be executed*/ $i++; 
                } 
                else { 
                $(this).prop('disabled', 1);
                $(this).hide();             
                }   
            }); 

            $('#prev').click(function() {
                $('#next').show();
                });

        var $n = 1; 
        $('body').on('click','#prev',function(){ 
                if ($n < 3) { /*functions to be executed*/ $n++; 
                } 
                else { 
                $(this).prop('disabled', 1);
                $(this).hide(); 
                } 
            });

            $('#next').click(function() {
                $('#prev').show();
                });
```

Comment: What's not working?  Maybe provide a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just forgot to reset your counters:

```
   var $i = 1; 
   var $n = 1;
    $('body').on('click','#next',function(){ 
            if ($i < 3) { /*functions to be executed*/ $i++; 
            } 
            else { 
               $(this).prop('disabled', 1);
               $(this).hide();
               $("#prev").show(); // <- show here
               $i = 1;             
            }   
        }); 


    $('body').on('click','#prev',function(){ 
            if ($n < 3) { /*functions to be executed*/ $n++; 
            } 
            else { 
               $(this).prop('disabled', 1);
               $(this).hide(); 
               $("#next").show(); // <- show here
               $n = 1;
            } 
        });
```